# Windows Phone 10 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, emulation

I need to develop an app which is for  Windows phone 10 app.Now Currently I have Following requirements.

1.Installed Visual Studio 2015

But I need Windows Phone 10 Emulator or Windows Phone 10 Device.Unfortuanatly Windows phone 10 Device is not yet Released by microsoft in India.so i need to go for Emulator.But My system is not Supporting SLAT.Therefore I can't go for Emulator.then I wanted to know that is there any Option to run or test my Project?

Thank you.

Comment: you can install the w10 mobile insider preview on any wp8 phone

Comment: Using Preview installation can I able to test my application?

Comment: yes, you can deploy to the device with vs2015

Comment: Okay Thank You.I will check it out.